# scipy curve_fit not working correctly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression, curve-fitting

It seems like it only fits the first parameter.

This went all great when I tried to generate a curve with the curve_fit example but not when I use my own data.

Here is my raw data: https://pastebin.com/0hs2JVXL

Which for the simplicity I am converting to ingeger numbers so here is the data im feeding to `curve_fit`: https://pastebin.com/2uP0iyTw

This is the curve I'm trying to fit (basically the formula for lognormal distribution with a scale value):

```
def func(x, k, s, u):
    x=np.array(x)
    return k * (1 / (x * s * np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))  *  np.exp(  - np.power((np.log(x)-u),2)  /  (2*np.power(s , 2)))
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
graphData.append(
    {
        'x': xdata,
        'y': ydata,
        'name': "data",
        'mode': 'lines'
    }
)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

graphData.append(
    {
        'x': xdata,
        'y': func(xdata, *popt),
        'name': "" + "[Fit]",
        'mode': 'lines'
    }
)
```

But this is the output data I'm getting: https://pastebin.com/WjaTH9wQ

And these are the parameters it is setting: `k=33.06185171  s= 1.  u=1.`

And to visualize:

[image]

I am not sure at all why this is not working.

Comment: Have you tried adding initial guesses close to the result you expect with the `p0` argument ?

Comment: @jadsq I will try this as soon as possible. I would want to automate this in the future for different graphs of the same shape so I'm not sure if relying on guesses is a good idea

Comment: Here is an example of using the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to create the p0 initial parameter estimates for curve fitting, the example fits data from Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes to a double Lorentzian peak equation: https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit - modify this code for your specific case and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using one of the ideas in the comments I got it to work:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(open("scipycurve.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
xdata = data[:,0]
ydata = data[:,1]
    
def func(x, k, s, u):
    x=np.array(x)
    return k * (1 / (x * s * np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))  *  np.exp(  - np.power((np.log(x)-u),2)  /  (2*np.power(s , 2)))

p0 = [1000,1,10]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.plot(xdata, ydata, label='Data', marker='o')
pyplot.plot(xdata,  func(xdata, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]), 'g--')
pyplot.show()

print (popt)
```

[image: plot of data and fitted curve]

`[  6.84279941e+07   5.09882839e-01   1.05414859e+01]`

Hope it helps. Just looks like the algorithm needs some help in this case by giving it parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me is adding a different method argument to curve_fit:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, method='dogbox')
```